# versionName cannot be set on a mergedFlavor directly, updated to gradle 5.1.1

Tags: android, groovy, build, android-gradle-plugin

I have updated to Gradle distribution 5.1.1 from 3.1.1, it involved lot of changes including updating androidX support library. For some reason build keeps on failing asking to change the way versionName is set in merged flavor. I am unable to figure out what exactly am i missing, have already added code suggested by gradle build result.

Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.40'
System.properties['com.android.build.gradle.overrideVersionCheck'] = 'true'
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://nexus.dminc-gtc.com/nexus/content/groups/public/' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone' }

    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    google()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    //annotationProcessor  'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    classpath 'com.dminc.gradle:android-release-plugin:1.0.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'
    classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.1.5'
    classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.5"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    classpath 'com.github.alexfu:androidautoversion:3.0.2'
 }
}

  repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  maven { url 'https://nexus.dminc-gtc.com/nexus/content/groups/public/' }
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
  jcenter()
  flatDir {
      dirs 'libs'
  }
  maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }


  maven { url 'http://maven.localytics.com/public' }
  maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
  maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone' }

  maven {
      url 'https://maven.google.com/'
      name 'Google'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
//apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'android-release-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: 'checkstyle.gradle'
apply from: 'pmd.gradle'
apply from: 'findbugs.gradle'
apply plugin: 'com.github.triplet.play'
apply from: 'sonar.gradle'
apply plugin: 'com.github.alexfu.androidautoversion'

ext.androidAnnotationsVersion = '4.6.0'

android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    // These are applied to the manifest, to prevent nasty compat modes, use the latest you can.
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    renderscriptTargetApi 19
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}

releaseConfig {
    // Set to true to add the version number from the apk name (default is false)
    addVersionToApk false
    // No default for propertyFile, you HAVE to specify it, it will be interpreted by the plugin as follow: [root_dir]/[propertyFile]
    propertyFile "version.properties"
}


flavorDimensions 'white_label', 'server'
productFlavors {
    newmoove {
        // Assigns this product flavor to the "version" flavor dimension.
        // This property is optional if you are using only one dimension.
        dimension "white_label"
        applicationId 'com.app.newmoove'
        manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsApiKey: "*******************",
                                facebookAppId    : "*************"]


    }
    wexer {
        // Assigns this product flavor to the "version" flavor dimension.
        // This property is optional if you are using only one dimension.
        dimension "white_label"
        applicationId 'com.app.wexer'
        manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsApiKey: "*********************",
                                facebookAppId    : "*************"]


    }
    customfit {
        // Assigns this product flavor to the "version" flavor dimension.
        // This property is optional if you are using only one dimension.
        dimension "white_label"
        applicationId 'com.appname.app'
        manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsApiKey: "**********************"]

    }
    dev {
        dimension "server"
        applicationIdSuffix ".devtest"
        versionNameSuffix "-dev"

    }
    integration {
        dimension "server"
        applicationIdSuffix ".integration"
        versionNameSuffix "-integration"

    }
    staging {
        dimension "server"
        applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
        versionNameSuffix "-staging"

    }
    live {
        dimension "server"

    }
}
// A lot of 3rd party libraries contain similar stuff.
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'LICENSE.*'
    exclude 'NOTICE.*'
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
}
lintOptions {
    quiet true
    abortOnError false
    ignoreWarnings true
}

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.versionNameOverride = "5.0.1.91-5.0.1"
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
implementation(name: 'Android-ViewPagerIndicator', ext: 'aar')
implementation(name: 'Fontify-release', ext: 'aar')
implementation(name: 'HoloGraphLibrary-release', ext: 'aar')
implementation(name: 'slidingmenu-release', ext: 'aar')
implementation 'com.mani:ThinDownloadManager:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.github.johnkil.print:print:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core:3.1.0@aar'
implementation 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-manipulation:3.1.0@aar'
implementation 'com.edmodo:rangebar:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.1'
implementation 'com.github.johnkil.android-appmsg:appmsg:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.0'
implementation 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.9.1'
implementation 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:11.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.0'
implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.4'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1'
// or 1.4-beta1
releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
// or 1.4-beta1
testImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
// or 1.4-beta1
implementation 'com.localytics.android:library:5.4.0'
implementation 'com.github.tony19:timber-loggly:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
implementation 'com.github.mmin18:realtimeblurview:1.1.0'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.9'
implementation 'com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.7.5'
implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'
implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation('com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.0.3') {
    exclude(module: 'support-v4')
    exclude(module: 'appcompat-v7')
}
implementation 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M4'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.4'
implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
implementation "org.androidannotations:rest-spring-api:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
implementation "org.androidannotations:rest-spring:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
implementation "org.androidannotations:ormlite-api:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
implementation "org.androidannotations:ormlite:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.1.0'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
implementation('androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0') {
    force = true
}
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'
implementation 'com.otaliastudios:nestedscrollcoordinatorlayout:1.0.1'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

//rx
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.2.0'

implementation group: 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins', name: 'android-apt', version: '1.8'
}
```

No matter what i do i am unable get pass the below error while building project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make this change(suggested in error window) in build.gradle and make clean build.

Comment: hi, i have already done that you can see those changes above dependency block in my gradle, also have tried clean build.

Comment: Even after clean build your getting same error? May be try building from Terminal. 'gradlew clean' and 'gradlew assembleDebug'

Comment: clean and assembling from terminal didnt worked either. :/